# Why does Grouping does not activate until I click a header, despite having groupBy in the table constructor

Tags: tabulator

The `groupBy` table parameter does not render my table in grouped layout until I actually click in the header area. I want my table to render with the table grouped according to the `"category_id"` field.  I have specified `groupBy:"category_id"`.

I've tried all the various CSS included with Tabulator, thinking maybe it was CSS related.  I also tried updating to the latest version (4.2.7).I tried calling `'table.redraw();'` on tableBuilt.

Code starts here. Note the `groupBy` parameter is listed as `category_id`.  Without the inclusion of this line it does not group.

```js
table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
clipboard: true,
clipboardPasteAction: "replace",
columnCalcs: "both",
columns: columnsDefault,
data: tableData,
groupBy: "category_id",
groupClosedShowCalcs: true,
groupToggleElement: "header",
index: "row_index",
height: "100%",
history: true,
layout: "fitColumns",
movableColumns: true,
movableRows: true,
pagination: "local",
paginationSize: 200,
paginationSizeSelector: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 50, 100],
reactiveData: true,
responsiveLayout: "hide",
selectable: false,
tableBuilt: tableComplete,
width: "500px",
}
```

the table renders, but without the grouping shown. No errors show in the console using dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may have found the issue.   I was calling the data from the REST server to build the tableData used as the data source.   I moved over to using the built-in Tabulator AJAX functions and now it's working.

It must have been the timing on the async delivery of the tableData to Tabulator.

I guess I could have redrawn the table using the redraw() method on tableBuilt parameter.